# Create all permutations with repeated elements, without repeating the permutation itself

Tags: python, unique, permutation, repeat

I have a string `'UUUUUUUUUDDDDDDD'` those are 9 `U`s and 7 `D`s.

I want to generate all permutations, like:

```
'UUUUUUUUUDDDDDDD'
'DUUUUUUUUUDDDDDD'
'DUUUUUDUUUDDDDUD'
'DUUDUUDUUUDDDDUU'
```

In other words, all possible strings with 9 `U`s and 7 `D`s

I'm trying to use `itertools.permutations()` but that function considers each `U` and each `D` as a different element so I get repeated permutations.

In the example below I will use a smaller string `UUD` just to demonstrate the problem with `itertools.permutations`:

```
for g in itertools.permutations('UUD'):
    print(g)
```

I get

```
('U', 'U', 'D')
('U', 'D', 'U')
('U', 'U', 'D')
('U', 'D', 'U')
('D', 'U', 'U')
('D', 'U', 'U')
```

I would want

```
('U', 'U', 'D')
('U', 'D', 'U')
('D', 'U', 'U')
```

Generating all possibilites and then adding them to a set to make them unique is not a viable solution, as there will be too many permutations to store in memory. I would like to generate them one at a time, work with it and discard it.

Comment: is your actual data much larger than the 9U 7D example at the top? Is it still binary (e.g. only two letters or etc?)

Comment: @AdamSmith The data could be larger. It is not binary, could have more letters.

Comment: darn, there's a good solution with `itertools.combinations` over `range(MAX_LENGTH, num_ds)` but it doesn't scale well.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a multiset permutation, in which case this might duplicate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284396/permutations-with-unique-values) and a few others (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676109/how-to-generate-all-the-permutations-of-a-multiset)). I've used the one which comes with sympy before-- is that an option?