# Iterating over distinct permutations of a vector in Pari/GP

Tags: combinatorics, pari-gp

I want to iterate over all distinct permutations of a vector. I have tried doing this by using `vecextract()` in combination with `numtoperm()`  to create a vector of permutations, and `vecsort(,,,8)` to remove equivalent permutations.

Unfortunately, this doesn't scale well: the maximum size of a vector within my current stack size of 4GB is less than 12!, and my machine only has 16GB.

Is there a way to do this without running out of  memory, maybe by generating the *k*-th distinct permutation directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing built into PARI for this. I would suggest reading [How to generate all the permutations of a multiset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676109/how-to-generate-all-the-permutations-of-a-multiset).

Comment: I suspected that was the case and will roll my own solution. A negative answer is much more useful than no answer at all!

Answer (score 1):

Use `forperm`.

```
forperm([1,1,2,3], v, print(v))
```

Produces

```
Vecsmall([1, 1, 2, 3])
Vecsmall([1, 1, 3, 2])
Vecsmall([1, 2, 1, 3])
Vecsmall([1, 2, 3, 1])
Vecsmall([1, 3, 1, 2])
Vecsmall([1, 3, 2, 1])
Vecsmall([2, 1, 1, 3])
Vecsmall([2, 1, 3, 1])
Vecsmall([2, 3, 1, 1])
Vecsmall([3, 1, 1, 2])
Vecsmall([3, 1, 2, 1])
Vecsmall([3, 2, 1, 1])
```

Note that the input vector to `forperm` should be sorted for correct results.