# How do I get all possible orderings of 9 zeros and 9 ones using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, python-itertools, combinatorics

## I want to end up with a list with 48 620 nested lists, containing 9 zeros and 9 ones in different orders.

```
from itertools import permutations

print(list(permutations('000000000111111111', r=18)))
```

I assume the code above works, but every `0` and `1` is treated like an individual symbol, so for every ordering I get tons of repeats:

```
('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')
('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')
('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')
('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')
('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')
('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')
('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')
('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')
('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')
('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')
...
```

So, basically, how do I shuffle a list in every possible way, excluding repeats?

I tried to use every method from `itertools`, but I didn't find one that specifically does what i need.

Comment: if you want all 9-digit combinations of 0s and 1s, you can just use binary counting from 0 to (2^10)-1. should give you all combinations you need and is way easier to achieve than any permutations.

Comment: Where did you get 10890 from? You want to choose 9 slots from 18 to put the 1s in. Isn't that 18C9, or 48620 ?

Comment: No, I want all 18-digit combinations that contain 9 ones and 9 zeros with no repeats.

Comment: I think there is some contradiction in the question, do you want your lists to have 9 of each character (that's what you are describing) or 9 total (that's what your example shows)?

Comment: @lastchance Using maths. But now I see that I was wrong, it's actually 48 620.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676109/how-to-generate-all-the-permutations-of-a-multiset (@ScottHunter - yes you're right, I deleted my original comment)

Comment: @Sirko: that isn't what OP is asking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where 18 is the length of the list you want to generate and 9 is how many of them should be 0:

```
for x in itertools.combinations(range(18),9):
    print(tuple(('0' if i in x else '1' for i in range(18))))
```

The idea here is to use `combinations` to choose the set of locations that will be 0 for each of (in your example's case) 48620 lists.

Answer (score 0):

A simple one, and faster than the accepted solution (~100 ms vs ~170 ms):

```py
from itertools import product

for x in product('01', repeat=18):
    if x.count('0') == 9:
        print(x)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3c9KK8nMVMktSi0ry83OKFTJzC_KLShQKivJTSpNLuLjS8osUKhQy82AiGuoGhuo6CkWpBamJJbaGFppWXApAkJmmUKGXnF-aB1Kgrqlga6tgCZEBgYKiTKBEhSbETqjVMCcAAA)

Answer (score 0):

More solutions (`Kelly2` and `Kelly3`) and a benchmark:

```
  8.7 ± 0.1 ms  Kelly2
  9.1 ± 0.1 ms  Kelly3
 44.1 ± 0.4 ms  CtrlZ
101.4 ± 1.2 ms  Kelly
179.5 ± 0.7 ms  Scott_Hunter

Python: 3.11.4 (main, Sep  9 2023, 15:09:21) [GCC 13.2.1 20230801]
```

The new solutions prepare tuples of length 9 and then just combine them appropriately, which is relatively fast. (No generation+outfiltering of invalid ones like `Kelly` and `CtrlZ`, and no costly creation of each tuple like `Scott_Hunter`).

Code:

```py
from itertools import product, combinations
from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
import sys

def Kelly():
    return [
        x
        for x in product('01', repeat=18)
        if x.count('0') == 9
    ]

def Kelly2():
    xss = [[] for _ in range(10)]
    for x in product('01', repeat=9):
        xss[x.count('1')].append(x)
    return [
        x + y
        for xs, ys in zip(xss, xss[::-1])
        for x in xs
        for y in ys
    ]

def Kelly3():
    xs = [*product('01', repeat=9)]
    xss = [[] for _ in range(10)]
    for x in xs:
        xss[x.count('0')].append(x)
    return [
        x + y
        for x in xs
        for y in xss[x.count('1')]
    ]

def Scott_Hunter():
    return [
        tuple(('0' if i in x else '1' for i in range(18)))
        for x in combinations(range(18),9)
    ]

def CtrlZ():
    hi = int("111111111000000000", 2)
    lo = int("111111111", 2)
    return [
        tuple(f"{x:018b}")
        for x in range(lo, hi + 1)
        if x.bit_count() == 9
    ]

funcs = Kelly, Kelly2, Kelly3, Scott_Hunter, CtrlZ

print(Kelly() == sorted(Kelly2()) == Kelly3() == Scott_Hunter() == CtrlZ())

times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):5.1f} ± {stdev(ts):3.1f} ms '
for _ in range(25):
    for f in funcs:
        t = timeit(f, number=1)
        times[f].append(t)
for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)

print('\nPython:', sys.version)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=nVTNjtMwED5xyVOMekm8662aVpW6kXrigsQFiRslivpjsxaJHdnOKqHqk3DZC9x5BR6DE4-C7dhtut0KgS-Jx-OZ7_s8M1-_151-EPzp6Vuj6d3i16vfVIoKmCZSC1EqYFUtpIZail2z1Ri2otowvtZMcBU5X80qwnRw7Hf9idLGT2m2PYapyJpjY9-Rx8ibVKeiaEcovCVl2SUoi8AsSXQjOazcxq72-EeFhBYYD5iSeJLG2NyoyVov0wU6ejIK7XgrGm59YgTLJdy7w3yQcRpStkrBElar3GUobAa55p9Ikk5QHv09872P42OtjqnTGOXjdV0TvktadIUe3EJ3TlFh6JTN9oXViQmIXdQsu0tzdClGq85snbV16oLt7MTWkr25wiT_V0VadYX85P_IX6N0IeyQ4fut0Lp4Y86IvFpIuqlLklhgtj6YCwqkVARMPJeIDYguEHpB7GETJEdPfI-GaF5rWX4IMB6YUZIZ0KM0rElYIwzT_mYpLrxOh1eY0NG-zSbpYnMYvYC0B1cKbBHcQvqsOTZMF72Y591BG761b-9qBvtG8d8ZPhMa90SjqJYWue9iG02Z9ia7JHSZs4UitP_nz2UtXjIURXaMWAB7moGvP2r5OGAHp6-dLiqhXmDtSlXDDaRk5vy19fcYXLgVzdEqm-f5UE4a7-1QSrRC2Xyc0gP8_AF7N6GcbeZslYI4etYE07lPfQ7u1AfaIOrHYUIx8KbaELkcvEAAFdpDo-gYyuN2ETF8Jt3S0fUZe6mDABjouCj4uiJFgcI7xB_5OzfaM9PXZsaOH4lUpl5RP-j9vA9z_w8)

Answer (score -1):

Your question is slightly ambiguous. Do you want the output list to have strings 9 characters long or 18? I'm assuming 18, because you said "containing 9 zeros and 9 ones"

The following code works, but I must warn you, it's terribly slow. You might want to consider just storing the output in a text file or something so you don't have to compute it every time.

```py
import itertools

def merge_tuples(items: list[tuple]) -> list[str]:
    new_items = set()
    for tup in items:
        new_items.add("".join(tup))
    return list(new_items)

inp_string = ('0'*9) + ('1'*9)
output = merge_tuples(list(itertools.combinations(inp_string, 18)))
```